# Mysql IF statement always return true

Tags: mysql

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but here is the thing:

```
IF 1=2 THEN
    SELECT 'success';
END IF;
```

Works fine, the statement is false and the select query is not run, but if I add anything before the if statement:

```
select 'hello world';
IF 1=2 THEN
    SELECT 'success';
END IF;
```

The if statement enters and runs the query, why? what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why should I provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example for any SQL query question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: seems fine to me in the last mysql version https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=755551f2a2ac3c19734a2c1c03473c7c

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @nbk answer it seems that inside a stored procedure it works fine.
Was using Datagrip to test the plain query and was not getting the correct flow, but inside a stored procedure everything works great.
Thanks.

Comment: ??? The if statement only exists in a procedure/function/trigger.  Datagrip or not, whatever you were trying was highly unlikely to be what you meant to be trying